# Docker PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'tmp'

Tags: python, docker, scrapy, dockerfile

I am new to docker and have built a custom container to run my spider on my cloud server. My scraper is built using python 3.6, scrapy 1.6, selenium and using docker to run everything in one container. When starting the spider I have scrapy open_spider method that runs another python script in the directory that generated the urls for scrapy to crawl. The script saves the links in a text file however, I am getting PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'tmp.

I have attempted to run chmod 777 and a+rw on the tmp folder so it will allow me to create the text file but I am still getting permission denied error. I have been researching this for days and cannot figure out how to fix this.

The OS on my laptop is ubuntu 18.04.

Below is the link to my docker file

Dockerfile

```
FROM scrapinghub/scrapinghub-stack-scrapy:1.6-py3
RUN apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install zip unzip jq libxml2 libxml2-dev
RUN printf "deb http://archive.debian.org/debian/ jessie main\ndeb-src http://archive.debian.org/debian/ jessie main\ndeb http://security.debian.org jessie/updates main\ndeb-src http://security.debian.org jessie/updates main" > /etc/apt/sources.list


#============================================
# Google Chrome
#============================================
# can specify versions by CHROME_VERSION;
#  e.g. google-chrome-stable=53.0.2785.101-1
#       google-chrome-beta=53.0.2785.92-1
#       google-chrome-unstable=54.0.2840.14-1
#       latest (equivalent to google-chrome-stable)
#       google-chrome-beta  (pull latest beta)
#============================================
ARG CHROME_VERSION="google-chrome-stable"
RUN wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - \
  && echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list \
  && apt-get update -qqy \
  && apt-get -qqy install \
    ${CHROME_VERSION:-google-chrome-stable} \
  && rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /var/cache/apt/*

#============================================
# Chrome Webdriver
#============================================
# can specify versions by CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION
# Latest released version will be used by default
#============================================
ARG CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION
RUN CHROME_STRING=$(google-chrome --version) \
  && CHROME_VERSION_STRING=$(echo "${CHROME_STRING}" | grep -oP "\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+") \
  && CHROME_MAYOR_VERSION=$(echo "${CHROME_VERSION_STRING%%.*}") \
  && wget --no-verbose -O /tmp/LATEST_RELEASE "https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE_${CHROME_MAYOR_VERSION}" \
  && CD_VERSION=$(cat "/tmp/LATEST_RELEASE") \
  && rm /tmp/LATEST_RELEASE \
  && if [ -z "$CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION" ]; \
     then CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION="${CD_VERSION}"; \
     fi \
  && CD_VERSION=$(echo $CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION) \
  && echo "Using chromedriver version: "$CD_VERSION \
  && wget --no-verbose -O /tmp/chromedriver_linux64.zip https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/$CD_VERSION/chromedriver_linux64.zip \
  && rm -rf /opt/selenium/chromedriver \
  && unzip /tmp/chromedriver_linux64.zip -d /opt/selenium \
  && rm /tmp/chromedriver_linux64.zip \
  && mv /opt/selenium/chromedriver /opt/selenium/chromedriver-$CD_VERSION \
  && chmod 755 /opt/selenium/chromedriver-$CD_VERSION \
  && sudo ln -fs /opt/selenium/chromedriver-$CD_VERSION /usr/bin/chromedriver


#============================================
# crawlera-headless-proxy
#============================================

RUN curl -L https://github.com/scrapinghub/crawlera-headless-proxy/releases/download/1.1.1/crawlera-headless-proxy-linux-amd64 -o /usr/local/bin/crawlera-headless-proxy \
 && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/crawlera-headless-proxy
RUN chmod a+rw app/cars/spiders
RUN chmod a+rw app/cars/tmp
COPY ./start-crawl /usr/local/bin/start-crawl
ENV TERM xterm
ENV SCRAPY_SETTINGS_MODULE cars.settings
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
COPY . /app
RUN python setup.py install
RUN chmod a+rw app/cars/tmp
```

Heres the link to my setup.py file

```py
# Automatically created by: shub deploy

from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='cars',
    version='1.0',
    packages=find_packages(),
    entry_points={'scrapy': ['settings = cars.settings']},
)
```

Comment: Maybe update your Docker version?

Comment: The dockerfile you posted doesn't have any problem (I built it on my machine), so either you have no permissions to use docker or there's a problem in your setup.py script.

If you post it I can take a look

Comment: @MicheleLambertucci my guess is I dont have the permissions but not 100% sure as I am new to docker and deploying it in the cloud. Here is the link to my setup.py file https://www.pastiebin.com/5defd230e2546

Comment: @dcarlo56ave Do not put external links as they can be broken by making your question useless for future readers. Put all the code in your question

Comment: @eyllanesc sorry about that and will do.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to your Dockerfile:

```
RUN adduser --disabled-login dockeruser
USER dockuser
RUN chown dockuser:dockuser -R /tmp/
```

Note: If `--disabled-login` also doesn't work, use `--disabled-password`

Comment: When I run that I am getting Option d is ambiguous (debug, disabled-login, disabled-password) I am assuming you mean --debug.

Comment: Thank you for the response but that still gave an error. Error The command '/bin/sh -c chown dockuser:dockuser -R /tmp' returned a non-zero code: 1: {'code': 1, 'message': "The command '/bin/sh -c chown dockuser:dockuser -R /tmp' returned a non-zero code: 1"}
Error: Docker operation failed

Comment: chown: cannot read directory ‘/tmp/tmp.k7vv77Padw’: Permission denied
chown: changing ownership of ‘/tmp/’: Operation not permitted

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the 'setup.py' file from line:

```
RUN python setup.py install
```

needs to be executed with appropriate permissions?

Comment: Maybe but how do I do that